Concurrency with Python polars delta lake writes
I'm using Python Polars to append a dataframe to a local delta lake instance.  When I attempt to run more than one instance of the script, the initial running script is terminated with no error.  My understanding is that writing to delta lake in "append" mode should mitigate any write conflicts. The partitioning on source should separate writes as well.
df.write_delta(
    "data/collect",
    mode="append",
    delta_write_options={
        "partition_by": ["source", "year", "month", "day", "hour"],
    },
    storage_options= {
        "compression": "ZSTD",
        "compression_level": "22",
    },
)

Is there something I am missing here?

It's a common issue in Databricks as well, it throws:  io.delta.exceptions.ConcurrentAppendException
It's likely that Polars is not capturing the error correctly, hence I would open a GH issue.
In your case I would make sure your table is partitioned and you only write to one partition from each instance of your script.
